# "How do you understand this?" in French?

Tags: questions, formulation-idiomatique

I want to encourage the person to re-tell something with their own words or reflect on certain topic. The closest I can come up with is "Comment comprenez-vous cette information?".

Comment: without context, it's difficult to tell ;) I have tens of ways to say that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to ask a person to explain something in their own words, you could use the verb *paraphraser* (just as you could use the verb *to paraphrase* in English).

> - Paraphrasez cela.
> - Paraphrasez la phrase.
> - ...

You could also use *reformuler*:

> Reformulez avec vos propre mots.

Answer (score 2):

You can say "**Pouvez-vous reformuler la problématique?**". This expression is often used in the directives to write essays, directives given in French classes by the professors to the students..

Comment: Please, you have to write "problématique".

Comment: @HorsSujet - I replaced "le problème" by "la problématique", but I forget to change the accent :(.

Answer (score 0):

I would say:

*Comment voyez-vous ceci ?*

Comment: Not sure in which country, but not in France